# function vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V=\{f: f: \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Q}\}$ the set of all functions that map elements in $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. Furthermore $\mathbb{Q}$ is the field of the vector space.

I have to find a tuple $(v_i)_{i\in I}$ that is linearly independent. Could I choose $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}, x\mapsto x^i$. I know that $V=\{1,x,x^2,x^3,...\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Is the indexing set $I$ given to you? If you're free to choose any set $I$, then your choice is indeed correct for $I = \{0, 1, \ldots\}.$ (However, you could've chosen a simpler set $I$ as well.)

Comment: Yeah, $I \in \mathbb{N}$, so I guess it is okay. But what does tuple $v_i$ mean in this case? Is $(1,x)$ a possible tuple?

Comment: Do you mean $I \subset \Bbb N$? $I \in \Bbb N$ would mean that $I$ is some natural number, not a set. $(1, x)$ would be a possible tuple iff $I$ is a set of cardinality $2$. In general, the tuple $(v_i)_{i\in I}$ means a collection of $I$-many elements.

Comment: Sorry, $I\subset \mathbb{N}$. So $(v_i)_{i\in I}=\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,...\}$ where $|\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,...\}|=\infty$ is possible aswell?

Comment: Yes. That is possible precisely in the case where $I$ is countably infinite. (Since $I$ is a subset of $\Bbb N$, this is the same as saying that $I$ must be infinite.)

Comment: Is $\langle v_i : i\in \mathbb{N}\rangle _\mathbb{Q} =V$ then?

Comment: No. The function $0\mapsto 0,\;z\mapsto z^{-1}$ is not in the span of your set.

Comment: Well, you're right - I missed that. One more thing though. Shouldn't it be $(v_i)_{i\in I}=(1,x,x^2,x^3,...)$

Comment: Yes, it is that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Sir.